# Jenkins and shell script input

Tags: shell

I've got automated package configuration test that should also run eula and some other shell user interactions, all y/n style stuff.

I've googled this a quite bit now, however I haven't found anything quite useful yet. Also the parametrized build doesn't seem to be the resolution either (what little I understand about Jenkins). So far I've used free style project with several execute shell steps.

I've tried now like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/my/script.sh < input.txt
```

with input.txt containing few echos containing " \n"(to scroll down the eula) and "y" (to accept the eula).

Problem is that script in question calls second script that should be the recepient of the input. But now the whole input.txt is outputted before the eula starts and therefore it's not handled.

Is there better way of handling this sort of user input situations? My Jenkins experience is rather limited.

Comment: I removed the [tag:jenkins] tag, as this is not related to Jenkins. I've never really used it, but I think [tag:expect] is what you're searching for.

Comment: Whether `expect` is needed depends on details not given in the question. It's a heavyweight, big-hammer kind of tool -- best avoided where possible. (Actually, the *best* practice is to fix your `script.sh` to not prompt the user at all when stdin is not a TTY; most commercial installers will have some alternate input mode, be it environment variables, command-line arguments, or similar).

Comment: With respect to "outputted before the eula starts" -- it's only written to your first `script.sh`, vs your "second script", *if that first `script.sh` does anything that reads it*. If your first script (and everything it starts, other than of course the "second script" in question) never reads from stdin, then the contents on stdin will still be sitting there, ready to read, when the second script starts.

Comment: Bottom line: We need a the details of the situation -- ideally a [mcve] -- to actually provide useful feedback here; the appropriate technique to use depends on details not in the question.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I'll thinker with the expect and see what happens.

So the problem here is that script isn't mine and I cannot really touch it. It's external package eula&environment script that I'm trying to see if/when it breaks. And add build step for the package afterwards to see if it's also bueno.

I'm developing totally different stuff and this is something I'm testing it against, and it seems that the package is broken 50% of the time and it's a bummer to communicate it after something is already pending. But small startups, no dedicated integrators and all that :D.

Comment: Ok, I went with expect. It seemed to do everything required here without need to start hacking the scripts.

StephenKing, perhaps you can mark this as aswered (by you).